# R dplyr:: A function with name injection (LHS of :=) later referenced on RHS of :=

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am writing a function using `dplyr` package and other related packages, such as `tidyr` and `tidyselect`. After reading [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#name-injection) and many trials and errors, I was able to write a function that incorporates both data masking/tidy select and name injection to achieve partial goal.

```
compute_ratio <- function(numerator = dcdata,
                          denominator = pgdata,
                          bygroup = c('STUDY', 'SITE'),
                          nbydp = n_dc_bydp_ym,
                          numsuffix = dc_byss,
                          denosuffix = pg_byss){
  numerator %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(dplyr::pick({{ bygroup }})) %>%
    dplyr::summarise("n_{{numsuffix}}" := sum({{ nbydp }}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>%
    # Merge denominator data with numerator data
    dplyr::full_join(denominator, by = {{ bygroup }}) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate("cum_n_{{denosuffix}}" := cumsum("n_{{numsuffix}}"),
                  "ratio_{{numsuffix}}" := dplyr::if_else("cum_n_{{denosuffix}}" == 0, NA,
                                                        round("n_{{numsuffix}}" / "cum_n_{{denosuffix}}", 3)))
}
```

The current issue is in the last `mutate()`. I cannot figure out how to refer to the names which is a name injection in previous lines of the same function. For example, `"n_{{numsuffix}}"` is a data variable derived from `summarise()`. When I need to refer to this data variable later in the last `mutate()`, it now is not on LHS of :=, but the RHS of :=.

Any advice or guidance is appreciated. How to refer to the previous name injection as a data variable later in the same user-defined function?

I have tried `.data[[]]`, embracing `{{ }}`, `!!enquo`. All end with errors.

Sample numerator data - `dcdata`

```
structure(list(STUDY = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
    SITE = c("0187", "086108", "4603", "4304", "8617", "3205", 
    "0713", "086124", "086048", "6140", "0186", "4407", "086344", 
    "4413", "061027", "4115", "3403", "086009", "8618", "086020"
    ), n_dc_bydp_ym = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Sample denominator data -- `pgdata`

```
structure(list(STUDY = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    SITE = c("0186", "0187", "0713", "3205", "3403", "4115", 
    "4304", "4407", "4413", "4603", "6140", "8617", "8618", "061027", 
    "086009", "086020", "086048", "086108", "086124", "086344"
    ), n_pg_byss = c(2705L, 371L, 1495L, 404L, 1357L, 2089L, 
    456L, 886L, 830L, 5034L, 912L, 1739L, 1991L, 60L, 18L, 858L, 
    666L, 759L, 28L, 171L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Test

```
test_ratiofun <- compute_ratio(numerator = dcdata,
                               denominator = pgdata,
                               bygroup = c('STUDY', 'SITE'),
                               nbydp = n_dc_bydp_ym,
                               numsuffix = dc_byss,
                               denosuffix = pg_byss)
```

Comment: This seems like an interesting question, but it is not reproducible and it is far from minimal. Could you please provide a small sample data set to test it on as well as the desired result for that sample data so we can tell if it's working properly? Built-in data, simulated data, or copy/pasteable data shared with `dput()` would all be great. Just keep it minimal--don't share 100 rows of data when 10 will do.

Comment: It would also probably help if you could edit your function to be **minimal**. If the issue is limited to the last mutate using previously injected names, it sounds to me like most of the body of your function works fine and is distracting from the problem. Could the problem be illustrated with one `summarize` injecting the names and then one `mutate` referring to them? That way you could omit the join, arrange, grouping and ungrouping, etc., and just focus on the problem.

Comment: In addition to @GregorThomas’s observations, which are absolutely correct, `dplyr::if_else(c"cum_n_{{denosuffix}}" … ` appears to be a typo.

Comment: Thanks, @GregorThomas and @Limey for your comments! I revised my question accordingly. I used `dput` as you suggested and copy/paste on my question. I am not sure if this is the appropriate way to share the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe theres a less convoluted way, but seems to work for what you want

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(glue)
myfunc <- function(x,numsuffix,denosuffix){
  
  n_text <- as.character(glue("n_{as_name(enquo(numsuffix))}"))
  
  group_by(x,
           Species) |>
    summarise("{n_text}":= sum(Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() |> 
    mutate(
   "cum_n_{{denosuffix}}" := cumsum(!!sym(n_text)))
}

myfunc(iris,whatever,also)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Species    n_whatever cum_n_also
  <fct>           <dbl>      <dbl>
1 setosa           73.1       73.1
2 versicolor      213        286. 
3 virginica       278.       564.
```

Comment: The way you suggested works! Thank you so much! Is my understanding correct that your idea is to take the `glue` part of name injection out of the pipes to create a separate R object. Then later, when I need to refer to the name of the R object, I can simply symbolize the R object?

Comment: yes, the way rlang uses glue, has its eccentricities, and the point is that its not available in all contexts, so to make it broadly available it should be explicit and hoisted out. Glad it could help you achieve your goals.